# Adding click event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make this function more versatile, so that if a user clicks on the image (#accordion-arrow), it will also trigger the .click event?

Here's both the JS and the markup for the accordion menu:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#DDAccordion > ul > li > a').click(function() {
            var checkElement = $(this).next()
            $('#DDAccordion li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('#DDAccordion ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }
            if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="DDAccordion">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">See All Products</a>
            <ul>
                <span id="DDAccordionGroup1">
    <li class="DDAccordionItem">
    <a href="/depot-deals/airflow/index.htm#airflow">
    <img src="/images/depot-deals/airflow_dd_icon.png" alt="Airflow">
    <span class="DDAccordionLink">Airflow</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="DDAccordionItem">
            <a href="/depot-deals/cable-certification/index.htm#cable-certification">
                <img src="/images/depot-deals/cable-certification_dd_icon.png" alt="Cable Certification">
                <span class="DDAccordionLink">Cable Certification</span></a>
        </li>
        </span>
        <span id="DDAccordionGroup2">
    <li class="DDAccordionItem">
    <a href="/depot-deals/borescopes/index.htm#borescopes">
    <img src="/images/depot-deals/borescopes_dd_icon.png" alt="Borescopes">
    <span class="DDAccordionLink">Borescopes</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="DDAccordionItem">
            <a href="/depot-deals/clamp-meters/index.htm#clamp-meters">
                <img src="/images/depot-deals/clamp-meters_dd_icon.png" alt="Clamp Meters">
                <span class="DDAccordionLink">Clamp Meters</span></a>
        </li>
        </span>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="horizRule"></div>
    <a href="#"><img id="accordion-arrow" src="/images/buttons_and_icons/btn_dwn-150.png"></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

My only thought is that the current handler contains data? Can I make that a part of the function?

JS is clearly not my strong-suit...I barely have the need to write functions, let alone talk about them.

Comment: You have invalid markup, the only child elements of a `<ul>` should be `<li>`, not `<span>`.

Comment: It looks as if your attempting to hide/show links based on which anchor element someone clicks. If you click on content inside the anchor element a click event will by fired for the anchor element itself, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hungerstar/jqd10x0L/1). It's definitely not clear what you're attempting to do, or at the very least, what the intended behavior is. As a result I'm not sure why you currently need to trigger a click on `<img>` when a click will be fire on the image's parent `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you jQuery selectors are not right.

```
('#DDAccordion > ul > li > a').click(function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next()
    $('#DDAccordion li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }
});
```

should be

```
$('#DDAccordion > ul > li > a').click(function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next()
    $('#DDAccordion li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }
});
```

Notice the dollar sign in front of the selector.

So, you can trigger the click event by implementing the link selector and triggering the click like this:

```
$('#DDAccordion > ul > li > img').click(function() {
$(this).closest('li').find('a').trigger('click');
//other code
});
```

So basically what this function is doing it listening to image clicks and goes up in the DOM structure and finds the closest **li** parent, than finds the link in it and triggers the click event on it.

Comment: I made a pure typo---the dollar sign is in the running code.